# magento 2 not working after the command bin/magento setup:di:compile

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.0

I ran below Command:

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

I have tried to upgrade my module with:

```
$ php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

The end result was:

> Please re-run Magento compile command

After doing this magento site is not working.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Magento SE, feel free to check out this post on how to ask a question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask . 
Please provide more information such as the error you're facing. What do you mean by "site is not working" ? Do you get an error ? A white page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please go to **app\bootstrap.php**

Do comment below line

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

& check for error in browser or check log files under `var/log` or `var/report` folders

Try to run below commands as well

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Good to hear that :)

Comment: after running the compile command, the page is blank, I clear & flush the cache after running the compile command but still, it's blank, if I run the setup: upgrade & content-deploy then only the page is loading well.

Answer (score 2):

Try to Run the Below Commands which will clear the Cache :

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Still Error there then paste exact error here

```
cd <your magento root>
rm -Rf var/generation
```

Comment: after running these command when i hit my page(localhost/magento2) i got "An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details".

Comment: please check your exception log file & paste error

Comment: where to find the exception log

Comment: you can find under : var/log

Comment: i updated my answer please try last command